# Jira .NET SDK: issue.Savechange() throw unknown exception

Tags: c#, .net, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

The .NET program I used to create Jira issues automatically failed to save the new created issue recently. The tool was working perfectly until a few days ago, so I guess the problem might be on the Jira server side. See the attached pics for exception details. What causes this exception? thanks.

The problem is resolved after removing following code, weird.
//new_issue.Priority = "None";

I tried following ways to set priority, but they both triggers that exception?

```
var new_issue = jira.CreateIssue("THINPRO");
new_issue.Components.Add("Security");
new_issue.Type = "Bug";
new_issue.Summary = "test;
new_issue.Description = "test;

/ set priority based on CVSS score use priority id
//1 = Highest 2 = High 3 = Medium 4 = Low 5 = Lowest 6 = (not used) 7 = None
if (score <= 0.0)
new_issue.Priority = "7";
else if (score >= 7.0)
new_issue.Priority = "2" ;
else if (score <= 4.0)
new_issue.Priority = "4";
else
new_issue.Priority = "3";

new_issue.SaveChanges();

 

// set priority based on CVSS score use priority name
if (score <= 0.0)
new_issue.Priority = "None";
else if (score >= 7.0)
new_issue.Priority = "High";
else if (score <= 4.0)
new_issue.Priority = "Low";
else
new_issue.Priority = "Medium";
new_issue.SaveChanges();





Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Response Content: 
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraRestClient.GetValidJsonFromResponse(IRestRequest request, IRestResponse response)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraRestClient.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraRestClient.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.IssuePriorityService.<GetPrioritiesAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.IssuePriority.<GetEntitiesAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.JiraNamedEntity.<LoadIdAndNameAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Issue.<ToRemoteAsync>d__158.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Issue.SaveChanges()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you properly authenticated?

Comment: Yes. I think so. Before this exception, the tool completed a successful Jira query. (jira.Issues.GetIssuesFromJqlAsync(jql, itemsPerPage, startAt);)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The problem is resolved after removing following code, weird.  

 

 //new_issue.Priority = "None";

Comment: Please always copy & paste relevant part of code, instead of a screenshot overlapped by the exception method. This helps others to help you.

Comment: @Ming, do other priority assingments work (e.g. `new_issue.Priority = "High";`) and do you have problem only with the `None` priority? Or no priorities can be assignements (via string or its ID)?

Comment: I don't know Atlassian.NET SDK but in this [example](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/e51934c33c796ba9b4c83bac75f740ed4d04bc2f/docs/how-to-use-the-sdk.md), they  create issues asynchronously (`await issue.SaveChangesAsync();`). Is there any difference?

Comment: Thanks, @CraZ. I've tried the “None", "High", "7", "2",  they all trigger that exception. I also tried “issue.SaveChangesAsync().Wait(), no difference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at my wits end, the problem might in the .NET SDK than in Jira REST API. To check that, simply try to create a new Jira issue manually via REST API using POST method and providing correct JSON. See [REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-createIssue).

Answer (score 0):

The value ***None*** is probably an invalid value.

In most (and default) Jira configuration, you cannot empty the ***Priority*** field. It's the system field and it must have a value from predefined list (usually something like *Blocker*, *Critical*, *Major*, *Minor*, *Trivial*).

Comment: Thanks. Pls see the updated the picture and code example.